# Using jQuery file upload plugin in a nested form_for

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I have a create product page that has a nested create photo inside of it. Photos belong to product and product has many photos. I am using [the jQuery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) but it requires you to hit save after uploading. This is a problem because it's in my product form and I can't save the photo without a product. So this is what happens when I hit save. "internal server error!" (above create product)

[image: The error I see]

And this is what gets output in console!

**console error**

```
 Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-02 15:01:38 -0400
Processing by ProductsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"z5BnHkHTqPZGKt+uWQs10wUEKkGlphXth0rqM82tjR0=", "product"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "condition"=>"", "quantity"=>"", "price"=>"", "ship_method"=>"", "ship_price"=>"", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x9699c3c @original_filename="eye.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[photos_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"eye.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130702-5814-cu2g3o>>}}}}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" = 'eQOQkRRSnzfA51iiDQ-90w' LIMIT 1
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "320x240>" '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt20130702-5814-vpw0ed'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt20130702-5814-vpw0ed'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt20130702-5814-b835qy'
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/eye20130702-5814-12toyjt20130702-5814-b835qy'
 Rendered products/new.js.erb (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 806ms

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:32:in `create'


Rendered /home/alain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (39.6ms)
Rendered /home/alain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.2ms)
Rendered /home/alain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb   within rescues/layout (52.8ms)
```

**new product page (HAML)**

```
= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { :id => "fileupload", :multipart => true } do |f| 

  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  %p
    = f.label :condition
    = f.text_field :condition
  %p
    = f.select :quantity, [['Quantity', nil], '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
  %p
    = f.label :price
    = f.text_field :price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " } 
  %p
    =f.select :ship_method, [['Shipping', nil], 'usps', 'ups', 'fedex']
  %p
    = f.label :ship_price
    = f.text_field :ship_price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " } 

  %p
    = f.fields_for :photos do  |fp| 
      =fp.file_field :image
      %br

  .files{"data-target" => "#modal-gallery", "data-toggle" => "modal-gallery"}
  %p.button
    = f.submit

:javascript
  var fileUploadErrors = {
  maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
  minFileSize: 'File is too small',
  acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
  maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
  uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
  emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
  };


/ The template to display files available for upload
%script#template-upload{:type => "text/x-tmpl"}
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    {% if (file.error) { %}
    <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
    <td>
      <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
    </td>
    <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
      </button>
      {% } %}</td>
    {% } else { %}
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
      <button class="btn btn-warning">
        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
      </button>
      {% } %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
/ The template to display files available for download
%script#template-download{:type => "text/x-tmpl"}
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
      {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[    file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
          {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
          <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
      <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
          <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
%script{:charset => "utf-8", :type => "text/javascript"}
  $(function () {
      // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
      $('#fileupload').fileupload();
      // 
      // Load existing files:
      $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimpFileupload'), 
          template;
        fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        console.log(files);
        template = fu._renderDownload(files)
          .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
        // Force reflow:
        fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
          template[0].offsetWidth;
        template.addClass('in');
        $('#loading').remove();
      });

  });
```

**product controller**

```
  def new 
    @product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
    @product.photos.build
  end

  def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])
  @photo = current_user.photos.new(params[:photo])

    if @product.valid?
      @product.save
      @photo.product_id = @product.id
      @photo.save
      render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
      @product.photos.build
      render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @photo }
    end
  end
```

What in the world should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @jjay225 for uploading product and image in a single request.

But you don't have to save them separately. You can save both in a single **save** command.

For this, you can make use of **accepts_nested_attributes_for** for this.
The benefit of this will be validations. if save for one record is failed, the other also fails.

Let me know if you need an example of this.

Comment: i would love an example of this!

Comment: Here is an example for image uploading:  
https://gist.github.com/deepakdargade/5928404

Answer (score 1):

Avoid complications, don't show the upload field when creating the product, show it at the edit page only.

Another option would be to send the product form first via AJAX, and display the image upload field at AJAX success.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion. Another approach will be uploading images to a temporary path first and move them to permanent path only when the product is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I would say browse for an image but don't upload it yet. Then enter your product details and post both to the server, of course get the Id to your newly created product before saving the link to your image to be able to link your image to the product you just saved.